# Dates within 10 months

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I want to sort objects, that contains a date. I only want the objects which date is 10 or less months away from the date today.

Example

```
const dates = [new Date('2019/05/20'), new Date('2019/08/03'), new Date('2020/03/20')]
```

In this example, I'm not interested in the last element, since its way more than 10 months away.
By saying

```
dates.forEach(e => {
  if (new Date().getMonth() + 10 < e.getMonth() {
    console.log('less than 10 months');
  }
}
```

Of course this won't work, since the max month is 12. It was just an example.

Any idea how I can solve this problem, with dates years away?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using [`setMonth`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) to calculate the currect future date:

```
const targetDate = new Date();
targetDate.setMonth(targetDate.getMonth() + 10);

dates.forEach(e => {
  if (targetDate < e) {
    console.log('less than 10 months');
  }
}
```

Note that if you're using a library like [`moment.js`](https://momentjs.com), you could do something like this:

```
const targetDate = moment().add(10, 'M');
dates.forEach(e => {
  if (mement(e).isBefore(targetDate)) {
    console.log('less than 10 months');
  }
}
```

Comment: FYI - `if (targetDate < e)` is also sufficient. :)

Comment: @MattJohnson Ahh you're right, for some reason I was thinking `<` would convert dates to strings, but `date.valueOf() === date.getTime()`

Comment: Thanks! Works flawless

Comment: [setMonth() docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setMonth) shows an interesting "last day of the month" overflow quirk. AND is this not odd?:  there's ambiguous zero-based, or not, arithmetic. i.e. `setMonth(3) is April - the 4th month. But `setMonth(15)` also yields 3 - so 12 is subtracted, not 11. I'm thinking of array indexing when we loop we must `Array.length - 1` to account for zero based indexing.

Comment: @radarbob Regarding the last days of the month, yes, that's a bit awkward. The logic is essentially, "measure current day of the month as an offset from the start of the month, then apply the same offset after adjusting the month." In those edge cases, the offset actually pushes the date into the next month. Regarding the 0-based index, this is actually fine as long as you just think of January as month 0. There are still 12 months in the year so `15 % 12` → `3`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g, my bad. I plead temp insanity. In light of the EOM quirk I was wanting to convince myself something was wrong - w/out writing some test code. Let that be a lesson everyone! Humility makes a better programmer.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC:
You can calculate the difference (in months) between the two dates:

```
function monthDiff(date1, date2) {
    var months;
    months = (date2.getFullYear() - date1.getFullYear()) * 12;
    months -= date1.getMonth() + 1;
    months += date2.getMonth();
    return months <= 0 ? 0 : months;
}
```

And then verify if the result is less than or equal to 10 using your forEach or you can use array.filter.